# How to solve wp_cache_get Wordpress Xampp Fatal error

Tags: wordpress, xampp, fatal-error

I have edited yesterday locally on my wordpress xampp installation several hours of content, texts and images.
The website was running all day.

When I wanted to start Xampp this morning the following message appeared:
**Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. While Trying to start Mysql on Xampp**

So i  Removed the Files which names start with aria_log in folder /xampp/mysql/data/

afterwards I was able to start xampp and call the dashboard in the browser.

now I get the following errors in my website:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_cache_get() in
C:\xampp\htdocs\tilders\wp-includes\option.php:165 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\tilders\wp-includes\l10n.php(63): get_option('WPLANG') 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\tilders\wp-includes\l10n.php(139): get_locale() 
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\tilders\wp-includes\l10n.php(766): determine_locale() 
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\tilders\wp-includes\load.php(1395): load_textdomain('default', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') 
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\tilders\wp-includes\class-wpdb.php(1198): wp_load_translations_early() 
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\tilders\wp-includes\class-wpdb.php(1858): wpdb->select('tilders', Object(mysqli)) 
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\tilders\wp-includes\class-wpdb.php(734): wpdb->db_connect() 
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\tilders\wp-includes\load.php(562): wpdb->__construct('tilders', 'tilders', 'tilders', 'localhost') 
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\tilders\wp-settings.php(124): require_wp_db() 
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\tilders\wp-config.php(99): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') 
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\tilders\wp-load.php(50) in C:\xampp\htdocs\tilders\wp-includes\option.php on line 165

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function set() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\tilders\wp-includes\l10n.php:784 
Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\tilders\wp-includes\l10n.php(872): load_textdomain('default', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 'de_DE') 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\tilders\wp-includes\class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(47): load_default_textdomain() 
#2 [internal function]: WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->handle() 
#3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\tilders\wp-includes\l10n.php on line 784
```

So far I have tried the following:

- Renamed all plugin folders
- have replaced the following folders and main directory files
  /wp-admin/
  /wp-includes/
  and .php files in the site root
- renamed the folder w3tc-config to w3tc-config.delete
- renamed all theme folders without "twentytwentytwo"

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have had the tables repaired under mysql admin. And the XAMPP database user had no more rights on his database.
This has solved the error

Answer (score 0):

Wrong database settings in `wp-config.php` for me.

I forgot and left DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD and DB_HOST empty during a staging installation.

But either wp-admin/ and wp-cli exited dued to that `wp_cache_get()` being undefind fatal error, not by database connection issue.

In hindsight I could've had a clue by the presence of `require_wp_db()` in the php fatal error stack trace.

Thanks @Ahmet for the clue about the database origin of the issue.